# Split alphanumeric and other character string

Tags: python, selenium

I want to split the string that look like:

```
"NumberTest_0821_0304-1.0"
```

I want to split it as

```
['NumberTest', '0821_0304', '-1.'0] or ['NumberTest', '0821_0304', '1.0']
```

I tried

```
re.split(r'\W+|\\_|\\-', str)
```

But this gives

```
['NumberTest', '0821', '0304', '1', '0']
```

Comment: `re.findall('[A-Za-z]+|\d[\d_]+|-?\d[.\d]+', 'NumberTest_0821_0304-1.0')`

Comment: It worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import re
str='NumberTest_0821_0304-1.0'
print(re.findall('[A-Za-z]+|\d[\_]+|\d[\.\d.]+',str ))
```